# Divisor is equal to zero, Need guidance with case statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is my query & I'm getting error divisor is equal to zero, I know i need to build this as a case statement just tried a few things and cant get it to work, thanks in advance.

```
NVL(ROUND(((SELECT PC.BUCKET_ACCUM_COST                                          
FROM   PART_CB PC                                                    WHERE  
PART_CB_NO = '201'                                                                          
AND PC.PART_NO = I.PART_NO
                                                                AND 
PC.CONTRACT = P.CONTRACT
                                                                AND 
PC.TOP_LEVEL_PART_NO || '' =

Z_BEL_FINANCE_API.GET_PART_COST_TOP_PART_NO(P.CONTRACT, P.PART_NO, 
P.COST_SET, P.ALTERNATIVE_NO,

P.ROUTING_ALTERNATIVE_NO)
                                                                AND 
PC.COST_SET = P.COST_SET
                                                                AND 
PC.COST_BUCKET_ID != 'SYS'
                                                                AND 
PC.TOP_ALTERNATIVE_NO =

Z_BEL_FINANCE_API.GET_PART_COST_TOP_ALT_NO(P.CONTRACT, P.PART_NO, 
P.COST_SET, P.ALTERNATIVE_NO,

P.ROUTING_ALTERNATIVE_NO)
                                                                AND

PC.TOP_ROUTING_NO = 
Z_BEL_FINANCE_API.GET_PART_COST_TOP_ROUTING_NO(P.CONTRACT, P.PART_NO, 
P.COST_SET, P.ALTERNATIVE_NO,

P.ROUTING_ALTERNATIVE_NO)
                                                                AND

PC.BUCKET_SEQ = Z_BEL_FINANCE_API.GET_PART_COST_BUCKET_SEQ(P.CONTRACT, 
P.PART_NO, P.COST_SET, P.ALTERNATIVE_NO,

P.ROUTING_ALTERNATIVE_NO)) /
                                             (SELECT WC_RATE
                                                 FROM   WCT
                                                 WHERE  WORK_CENTER_NO = 'COST1'
                                                                AND COST_SET = '1'
                                                                AND CONTRACT = P.CONTRACT)), 4), 0) MACHINE_SETUP_TIME,
```

Comment: It return 0 probably: `(SELECT WC_RATE FROM WCT WHERE WORK_CENTER_NO = 'COST1' AND COST_SET = '1' AND CONTRACT = P.CONTRACT)`

Comment: @mfgn: Please take some time to format your code nice. Hint: The editor has the`{}` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only dividing in this *mess* is here:

```
/ (SELECT WC_RATE FROM WCT ...)
```

If you don't want to divide with zero, you'll have to handle it.

For example, use `DECODE` (or `CASE`) and - if you want to get 0 as the result, divide with a very large number (e.g. 1E99)